# Custom Jquery Validation With AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I want to know how can we implement AJAX result in Jquery validation. For example i want to check through AJAX that username is availaible or not available in database and prompt user its availaibilty or non-avalaibility how can i do that? thanks in advance

Comment: I have solved this problem by sending credentials to my server and check the availaibility and using the response to show that username and password is valid or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea on how it looks

```
    $.ajax({
       url: 'yourusernamecheckpage.php',
       type:'post',
       data:{'username':$('#yourusername').val()},
       beforeSend:function(){
            //do a loading msg..like checking..

       },
       success:function(msg){
       if(msg == 'ok'){
        //username available
       }else{
        //username not available
       }
    },error:function(msg){

   alert(msg);
   }     


    });

//yourusernamecheckpage.php
//you can get the username as $_POST['username']:
//do your validation and 
echo 'ok';exit; 
//if available
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery validation plugin, and use its [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) validation method.

Comment: I figure it out. it is very simple just pass the username and password throgh post mehtod and retrieve it in controller and check in database and then through back the result